# How to implement microservice Saga in google cloud platform

Tags: microservices, google-cloud-pubsub, distributed-transactions, axon, saga

I am investigating solution to implement microservice Saga pattern in platform hosted in K8S in GCP.
There are 2 options: Eventulate Tram and Axon. However, these frameworks seem not to support message broker managed by cloud provider such as google-cloud-Pubsub whereas I do not want to deploy either Kafka or RabbitMQ to K8S since GCP support PubSub already.

So is there any way to integrate either Eventulate or Axon to use google cloud PubSub?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Uncertain about Eventuate's angle on this, but Axon works with extensions as message brokers other than [Axon Server](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server). Throughout Axon's lifecycle (read: last 10 years), some of these have been provided, but none are currently used for all types of messages defined by Axon Framework. So, you wouldn't be able to use Kafka for sending commands in Axon for example.

Reasoning for this? Commands, events and queries have different routing requirements which should be reflected by using the right tool for the job.

To be a bit more specific on Axon's side, the following extensions can be used for distributing your messages:

- [AMQP](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-amqp) -> for Events
- [Kafka](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka) -> for Events
- [JGroups](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-jgroups) -> for Commands
- [Spring Cloud Discovery](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-springcloud) -> for Commands

As you can tell, there currently is no Pub/Sub extension out there to allow you to distribute your messages. Added on top of that, my gut would tell me *if* it was available, then it would likely only be used for Event messages due to Pub/Sub's intent when it comes to being a message broker.

Luckily this actually makes it rather straightforward to create just such a extension yourself. Going into all the details to build this would be a little much, so I would recommend to have a look at Axon's AMQP extension first when it comes to achieving this. Hints on the matter are that for publication, you should add a component to handle Axon's events and publish them on Pub/Sub. For handling events, you are required to build a `StreamableMessageSource` or `SubscribableMessageSource`. These interfaces are used respectively by the `TrackingEventProcessor` and `SubscribingEventProcessor`, which in turn are the component in charge of dealing with the technical aspect of handling events.

By the way, if you would be building such an extension and you need a hand, it would be best to request this at AxonIQ forum, which you can find [here](https://discuss.axoniq.io/).

Last note, and rather important I'd say, is the argument that such a connector would not be able to deal with all types of messages. If you would require a more full fledged Axon application to run in a distributed fashion, I would highly recommend to give Axon Server a try prior to building your own solution from the ground up.